# SD card write limit - data logging

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, sd-card, fat

I want track/register when my system (a Raspberry Pi) was shut down, usually due to abrupt power loss.

I want to do it by recording a heartbeat every 10 minutes to an SD card - so every 10 mins it'd go to the SD and write the current time/date in a file. Would that damage the SD in the long run?

If there's only 100k write cycles to it, it'd have a bad block in a couple of years. But I've read there's circuitry to prevent it - would it prevent the bad block? Would it be safer to distribute the log in several blocks?

Thanks

Comment: It would depend on the make and model of your SD card, but with most modern cards I think you should be fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The general answer to this question is a strong "it depends". (Practical answer is what you already have; if your file system parameters are not wrong, you have a large margin in this case.) It depends on the following:

- SD card type (SLC/MLC)
- SD card controller (wear levelling)
- SD card size
- file system
- luck

If we take a look at a flash chip, it is organised into sectors. A sector is an area which can be completely erased (actually reset to a state with only 1's), typically 128 KiB for SD cards. Zeros can be written bit-by-bit, but the only way to write ones is to erase the sector.

The number of sector erases is limited. The erase operation will take longer each time it is performed on the same sector, and there is more uncertainty in the values written to each cell. The write limit given to a card is really the number of erases for a single sector.

In order to avoid reaching this limit too fast, the SD card has a controller which takes care of *wear levelling*. The basic idea is that transparently to the user the card changes which sectors are used. If you request the same memory position, it may be mapped to different sectors at different times. The basic idea is that the card has a list of empty sectors, and whenever one is needed, it takes the one which has been used least.

There are other algorithms, as well. The controller may track sector erase times or errors occurring  on a sector. Unfortunately, the card manufacturers do not usually tell too much about the exact algorithms, but for an overview, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling

There are different types of flash chips available. SLC chips store only one bit per memory cell (it is either 0 or 1), MLC cells store two or three bits. Naturally, MLC chips are more sensitive to ageing. Three-bit (eight level) cells may not endure more than 1000 writes. So, if you need reliability, take a SLC card despite its higher price,

As the wear levelling distributes the wear across the card, bigger cards endure more sector erases than small cards, as they have more sectors. In principle, a 4 GiB card with 100 000 write cycles will be able to carry 400 TB of data during its lifetime.

But to make things more complicated, the file system has a lot to do with this. When a small piece of data is written onto a disk, a lot of different things happen. At least the data is appended to the file, and the associated directory information (file size) is changed. With a typical file system this means at least two 4 KiB block writes, of which one may be just an append (no requirement for an erase). But a lot of other things may happen: write to a journal, a block becoming full, etc.

There are file systems which have been tuned to be used with flash devices (JFFS2 being the most common). They are all, as far as I know, optimised for raw flash and take care of wear levelling and use bit or octet level atomic operations. I am not aware of any file systems optimised for SD cards. (Maybe someone with academic interests could create one taking the wear levelling systems of the cards into account. That would result in a nice paper or even a few.) Fortunately, the usual file systems can be tuned to be more compatible (faster, leads wear and tear) with the SD card by tweaking file system parameters.

---

Now that there are these two layers on top of the physical disk, it is almost impossible to track how many erases have been performed. One of the layers is very complicated (file system), the other (wear levelling) completely non-transparent.

So, we can just make some rough estimates. Let's guess that a small write invalidates two 4 KiB blocks in average. This way logging every 10 minutes consumes a 128 KiB erase sector every 160 minutes. If the card is a 8 GiB card, it has around 64k sectors, so the card is gone through once every 20 years. If the card endures 1000 write cycles, it will be good for 20 000 years...

The calculation above assumes perfect wear levelling and a very efficient file system. However, a safety factor of 1 000 should be enough.

Of course, this can be spoiled quite easily. One of the easiest ways is to forget to mount the disk with the *noatime* attribute. Then the file system will update file access times, which may result in a write every time a file is accessed (even read). Or the OS is swapping virtual memory onto the card.

Last but not least of the factors is luck. Modern SD cards have the unfortunate tendency to die from other causes. The number of lemons with even quite well-known manufacturers is not very small. If you kill a card, it is not necessarily because of the wear limit. If the card is worn out, it is still readable. If it is completely dead, it has died of something else (static electricity, small fracture somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an informative answer.